# How do I Build Protocol Buffer from Source?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am trying to build a protocol buffer from the source code, but I could not do that. I am using Go and I would like to make some changes to the source code of the protocol buffer in Go and rebuild it again.

In the protocol buffer GitHub repository, there is a clear instruction to build protobuf binary in C++. Here is the [link](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/README.md). In the same repository, there are no clear instructions on how to build protobuf in Go.
I used brew install protoc-gen-go to install the protoc on a mac machine. It works fine, but I have a plan to make some changes in [protobuf-go](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go).

So, I guess the question is how do I recompile protoc?
I appreciate your answer in the style of a step.

Comment: Do you want to build a protocol buffer? That is, you have a .proto file and want to use it in Go code. Or do you want to modify and recompile `protoc`? If so, why do you want to modify and recompile `protoc`?

Comment: My current project idea is to control the message communications between nodes using grpc. So, to implement custom types of my messages and control policies, I wanna all my control policies to be in generated code. Basically, in the .proto file, the user will type the custom messages and their types. When the code is generated, all my policies for communication control will be generated in the generated codes after the .proto file is compiled by using protoc.

Comment: [I'm sure there's a better way to solve this problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) than by requiring a modified protoc. Perhaps rephrase your question to ask about your problem (providing customization) and mention you've considered altering protoc as a solution. For example, a pre-processor for the protocol buffer files, or by using existing protobuf features or by providing wrappers around the protocol buffers.

Comment: A short example of a protocol buffer file with your proposed custom messages would be useful.

Comment: Thanks, but the question is how to rebuild the binary. If I know that, my problem is solved. Currently, we only install the prebuilt binary file.

Comment: And then you have a new problem: maintaining and distributing an altered protoc binary. And your users have a new problem: using non-standard protocol buffer files with a non-standard protoc binary. "Change the compiler" is a solution of last resort.

Comment: Whether you're open to alternative solutions or not, please edit your question so it's clear to people what you're asking for.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. I am aware of your concerns. My question is only about how to recompile the binary. I have stated that in the question. The steps to rebuild the binary file. So, every time I make a change in the source code, I know how to recompile it.

Answer (score 2):

See [Protocol Buffer Basics: Go](https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/gotutorial/) in the Protocol Buffers Documentation.

After you've [installed the compiler](https://protobuf.dev/downloads) and protoc-gen-go plugin, run the compiler...

```
protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --go_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/addressbook.proto
```

`$SRC_DIR` is where your application's code lives, and `$DST_DIR` is where you want the Go code generated from the .proto file to live.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I would say this is the normal way of compiling the .proto file. 
My question is how to regenerate the protoc binary. I wanna the generated files .pb to have more functions that I can use in my go files.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the project by using the following command:

```
go test -mod=vendor -timeout=60m -count=1 integration_test.go -buildRelease
```

This snippet is from `release.bash`. It uses Go's testing framework as a build script.